# Згрузка и отображение процесса

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Использую этот код чтобы загрузить картинки

```
-(IBAction) downloadButton:(id)sender {

if(_downloadTask == nil){

            _url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"someUrl"];
            _url2 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"someUrl"];
            _downloadTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url1];
            _downloadTask1 = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url2];
           [_downloadTask resume];
           [_downloadTask1 resume];

        }
else
        [_downloadTask resume];
        [_downloadView removeFromSuperview];
        [_downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
        [_downloadButtonCancel removeFromSuperview];

    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{

    _paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory1 = [_paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
    _filePath1 = [_documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.png"];
    _fileExists1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_filePath1 isDirectory:false];

    _paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _documentsDirectory2 = [_paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
    _filePath2 = [_documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"2.png"];
    _fileExists2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_filePath2 isDirectory:false];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSData *urlData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url1];
    [urlData1 writeToFile:_filePath1 atomically:YES];

    NSData *urlData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url2];
    [urlData2 writeToFile:_filePath2 atomically:YES];
});
```

И этот код для отображения хода загрузки в процентах

```
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
        float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

        NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", ((progress / total) * 100)];

        NSLog(@"%.f%%", percentage);

       if (!_label) {



            _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 130, 42, 19)];

            _label.numberOfLines = 1;
            _label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
            _label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            _label.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
            _label.clipsToBounds = YES;
            _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

            [self.view addSubview:_label];

        }

        _label.text = percentage;
```

Проблема в том, что `label` не отображает загрузку от 1% до 100%. а беспорядочно показывает разные цифры. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ты ведь два урла сразу грузишь, вот они оба одновременно свой прогресс и показывают. Нужно или грузить их по очереди, или по параметру downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask определять какой это таск и менять соответствующий label. Также можно вести один общий прогресс для двух урлов.

Comment: А как сделать общий прогресс для двух url?

Comment: Запоминаешь количество скачанных байт для каждого таска, суммируешь, делишь на (total1+total2). Главное - по параметру определять какой урл вызвал метод делегата. Сейчас ты их никак не разграничиваешь.

Comment: Извините за тупой вопрос,  но как их разграничить? Я сделал ` if (_downloadTask1) {}  if  (_downloadTask2) {} ` но это не работает.  Могли бы вы показать как это сделать в коде?

Comment: Код "if (_downloadTask1) {} if (_downloadTask2) " просто проверяет что указатели не пустые. Нужно сделать так:

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
  if( downloadTask == _downloadTask )
      total1 = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
  if( downloadTask == _downloadTask1 )
      total2 = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
  }

Comment: просо сверяешь параметр downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask с переменными _downloadTask и _downloadTask1

Comment: все работает. Спасибо. Посмотрите, пожалуйста этот вопрос. Не могу разобраться. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553701/Загрузка-файлов